# crdb_adoplus.dll Unit Test Solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, crystal-reports

I am having trouble in VS2012 Unit Test Project with SAP Crystal Reports.

Below error is generated while in test case.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.SetDataSource(dataset); // Getting below quoted error.
```

Error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried this link but it didn't worked for me.
[Could not load file or assembly crdb_adoplus.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601741/solution-to-the-problem-of-file-crdb-adoplus-dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the change in the test runner config file i.e. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.config

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution to the one you have linked.

Change it however
from:

```
<!--<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>-->
```

to:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>

  </startup>
```