# Crystal Reports and .NET 4 - Could not load file or assembly (with useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false") crdb_adoplus.dll

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, clr

A little background - my application is currently built in .NET 3.5 but I would like to migrate it to .NET 4.0.  When I change all projects to point at .NET 4.0 my application runs fine until I try to open a Crystal Report.

My error is as follows:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've searched and there are quite a few answers to this question in the form of adding variations of the following to the app.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

However, this solution does not work for me.  I use another assembly in my project (more specifically, Intuit's ProFile) which does not work once I set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true".  I assume this is due to the fact some of their Tax Engines are pre v4 assemblies.

So my question is how I proceed from here?  Leaving my application in .NET 3.5 is really only a temporary fix.

Could I toggle useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy at runtime (i.e. set it to true before I load a Crystal Report) or is this a hack / even possible?

Is there a better way?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly crdb\_adoplus.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601741/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crdb-adoplus-dll)

Comment: If you look at the app.config code in my question you will see that it is identical to the accepted answer of the question you said my question "may be a duplicate" of, except that answer does not work for me.  I also stated I read quite a few similar questions that did not solve my question which is the reason for my post.  My question is not a duplicate, so please read the question more closely next time.  Thank you.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? (just checking as the older versions came with Crystal and the newer ones do not) I am having a similar issue on a project created in VS2008 and currently being maintained in VS 2013.

Comment: I'm using VS 2012 and 2013 (I've actually tried in VS 2010 to no avail as well).  I can't say for sure which version of VS this project was created in but I'm going to assume it was VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Something is out of sync on your runtime install/deployment. It should not be looking for "dotnet1" folder. Try removing all of the Crystal assemblies. Set project for .Net 4. Install the VS 2010 Crystal add-on, then install whatever SP of runtime engine.

Comment: I will definitely be giving this a try as soon as I get some free time.  Thank you very much for the suggestion and hopefully I can mark this as the answer in the near future :)

Answer (score -2):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll
```

Upload in path in error then continue. It will work.